# How to give back fetch data back to client application once it re-open in WCF service

Tags: wcf, notifications, duplex, wcf-callbacks, icallbackeventhandler

If application close before it gets data from WCF Duplex service I am planning to serialize that message and keep in WCF service hosted server. Once the application is re-open I want to notify the user that there is one message waiting. How can I achieve this?.

As I know once application is closed service will unsubscribe the user. So do i need DB mechanism to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance
Manjunath

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some code that writes back to a database boolean field when the message has been completed on the client. If the application closes then the code won't be hit, otherwise the flag will be set. You can then use this to create alerts for users.